# Nilradical of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am asked to compute the $nilrad(\mathbb{C}[X])$ and the reduction $\mathbb{C}[X]_{red}$.

$\textbf{DEFINITION:}$  An element $a \in R$ is nilpotent if $a^n = 0$ for some positive integer $n$.

$\textbf{DEFINITION:}$  $nilrad (R) =$ $\{$ nilpotent elements of $R$ $\}$ $= \bigcap\limits_{p \ \in  \ spec \ R} \mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal.

I got the following:

$nilrad(\mathbb{C}[X]) = \{0\}$ since $0$ is the only element in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $0^n = 0$ for some positive integer $n$.

Also, for the $\mathbb{C}[X]_{red}$, my answer is that $\mathbb{C}$ is reduced since $nilrad(\mathbb{C}[X]) = (0)$.  Also since $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is an integral domain, then $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is reduced.

Are both my answers correct?  When I am asked to compute the reduction of some ring $R$, is it just a yes or no question with some justification needed?

Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: Your answer to the first question is correct. For the second, I believe that the reduction of a ring $R$ is defined to be the quotient ring $R/\mathrm{nil}(R)$ - in your case, this would be $\mathbb{C}[X]/(0) \cong \mathbb{C}[X]$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim  Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: The answer to the first is correct, but the proof is incomplete. Why would a nilpotent element of ${\bf C}[X]$ be in ${\bf C}$?

Comment: @tomasz $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is the polynomial ring with complex coefficients, so $0$ is just the constant polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[X]$?

Comment: @mathamphetamines: yes, so? If $R$ is a ring with nilpotent elements, what is the nilradical of $R[X]$ (or, for an easier question, is it contained in $R$)?

Comment: @tomasz Yes the $nilrad(\mathbb{C}[X])$ is contained in $\mathbb{C}[X]$.  For $\mathbb{C}[X]_{red}$, is it just the $R/nil(R)$?  If so, should I use the First Isomorphism Theorem to find what this quotient ring is isomorphic to?